# Swift Error: when deleting from Parse, last item in a tableView causes a crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am displaying Parse data in a TableViewCell. When I delete it, the following function is called:

```
func deleteData () {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"myClass")
    query.whereKey("myInfo", equalTo: myArray[path]) 
     //path is a variable that is equal to indexPath.row
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {
                    object.deleteInBackground()
                    println("1")
                }
            }
        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I reload all the data from Parse, but there is a crash every time I delete *the last item*.

> [Error]: object not found for delete (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.5)

and also

> fatal error: Array index out of range

Comment: error says that what you are trying to deleting from array is not present into array so debug your code that might help you.

Comment: How do you set `path`?  Why don't you pass it as a parameter to the function rather than relying on the instance variable ?

Comment: I set path in the commitEditingStyle @Paulw11 . How would I pass it as a parameter?